# PHP insert <br /> whenever substring is longer than x characters

Tags: php, string, substring

I am trying to create some PHP code that will check the length of individual substrings within a string and insert "`<br />`" whenever a substring is longer than x characters.

The string is always of the following form:
aaa bbbbwer sdfr`<br />`ert tyuo sdh`<br />`ryt kkkkkkkkkkkk sdfg

So, say x=5, then I want that string to be converted into:
aaa bbbbw`<br />`er sdfr`<br />`ert tyuo sdh`<br />`ryt kkkkk`<br />`kkkkk`<br />`kk sdfg

How do I do this? Pls help!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any luck yet? I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think you can try wordwrap

```
<?php
$text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 20, "<br />\n");

echo $newtext;
?>
```

Result

```
The quick brown fox<br />
jumped over the lazy<br />
dog.
```

Comment: This does not split the words on every 5 characters like the OP asked for.

Comment: @Michiel Pater: yeah i just suggested an easier way to handle , i thought he might have designed the string unknowing of this function ! your answer is to the point , i just gave a suggetion

Answer (score 2):

You could slice words that contain more than x characters using the following code.

It will first split the string into lines by using the function `explode()`. It explodes on the `<br />` tags. Then it will loop through the lines and split the line into words for each line. Then for each word it will add `<br />` after every 5 characters. and add the edited line to the variable `$new_string`. Ath the end it echoes variable `$new_string` to display the edited string.

- To change the maximum word length, just change the variable `$max_length`.
- To change the input string, just change the variable `$string`.

**Code**

```
$string      = 'aaa bbbbwer sdfr<br />ert tyuo sdh<br />ryt kkkkkkkkkkkk sdfg';
$max_length  = 5;

$lines       = explode('<br />', $string);
$new_string  = '';

foreach($lines as $line)
{
    $words = explode(' ', $line);

    foreach($words as $word)
    {
        $new_string .= substr(chunk_split($word, $max_length, '<br />'), 0, -6) . ' ';
    }

    $new_string = substr($new_string, 0, -1) . '<br />';
}

echo $new_string;
```

**Output**

```
aaa bbbbw<br />er sdfr<br />ert tyuo sdh<br />ryt kkkkk<br />kkkkk<br />kk sdfg<br />
```

Answer (score 0):

And the [wordwrap function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) don't make whats you wants ?

Comment: This does not split the words on every 5 characters like the OP asked for.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies!

Although Michiel's answer probably addresses best the problem as I wrote it here, using wordwrap will work fine as well.

Cheers!

Comment: @RLJ I've merged your accounts together, you can now accept an answer as correct.  I'd suggest you register; also, [please read this Faq entry about cookie-based accounts.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account/44562#44562)